# Change style DatePicker dialog android

Tags: android, datepicker, android-theme

I like to change style to DatePicker widget in android. I use the theme Theme.Holo.Light and here is the dialog I got:

[image]

I like to change the color of the blue line after the dialog title. On click on buttonOK and buttonCancel I like to change the button color from blue to another color.

Does somebody have any idea?